# getting error "There was a issue with network [400]" while playing You tube video

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am playing you Tube video using Android You tube API. Some of the URL are working fine but in some URL i found error message on screen saying  "There was a problem with network [400] Tap to retry". Internet is connected.Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is saying your url is incorrect. It is bad request error.

Comment: No. I checked URL on window browser. it is working.

Comment: is there any code?

Comment: Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this,
                            Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, videoId, 0, true, false);

                    if (intent != null) {
                        if (canResolveIntent(intent)) {
                            startActivityForResult(intent,
                                    REQ_START_STANDALONE_PLAYER);
                        }

Comment: Any one can please help me out as its very urgent.

Comment: which are all the URL you tried. which URL not working. Kindly Update on your question.

Comment: Hi Thanks for giving me clue as those video is not working in which time slot is added like : "XgOGh7AoEMA&t=185s" as i resoloved this by removing time parameters like "XgOGh7AoEMA" but as per my requirement i want to play this video from particular time frame. I appreciate if you could please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/FQoBYsObhBQ/7TVtMuGxyk8J), Your solution.

I think Give ONLY the **YouTube** ID and not the entire YouTube URL to the `loadVideo()` function.

**UPDATE:**

if you want jump to a specific time in the video.

The API provides two methods to jump playback:

– `seekToMillis()` – Seeks to the specified time in the video.

– `seekRelativeMillis()` – Seeks forward or backwards by the specified number of seconds.

More info [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/)

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**gNRN7lUU3tM from the url and only give gNRN7lUU3tM as url to the youtube player. It will work fine